# Move data with the same suffix into empty folders in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.1

I have been able to create 75 empty group folders with this code:

```
import arcpy

lyr_folder = r"C:\_geodata"


for i in range(1, 76):
    
    
    group_file = "Gruppe{}.lyrx".format(i)
    
    group_path = os.path.join(lyr_folder, group_file)
    
    group_layer = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(r"C:\_geodata\Gruppe1.lyrx").listLayers()[0]

    group_layer.name = "Rute_{}".format(i)
    arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT").activeMap.addLayer(group_layer)
```

My gdb consists of feature classes, 75 of each:

Building_1-75, Roads_1-75, Info_1-75, Environment_1-75.

It's basically just different data for a quadrant in a grid. Now, I would like to add them to each group layer, that has the same suffix. The empty groups are organized like this:

[image]

How would I go about this in arcpy?